# docker tutorial how to install package

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, updates, apt-get, dockerfile

I'm just following the [getting started](https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_four/) of docker and I'm a bit lost.
I've create a mydockerbuild folder in my document and a dockerfile with this code (from the tutorial)

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

Then following the tutorial I run this command:

```
docker build -t docker-whale .
```

I got the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 0 : FROM docker/whalesay:latest
 ---> fb434121fc77
Step 1 : RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
 ---> Running in dafe01cfcd2b
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fortune-mod fortunes-min librecode0
Suggested packages:
  x11-utils bsdmainutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fortune-mod fortunes fortunes-min librecode0
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1961 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4817 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main librecode0 amd64 3.6-21
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe fortune-mod amd64 1:1.99.1-7
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe fortunes-min all 1:1.99.1-7
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe fortunes all 1:1.99.1-7
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/recode/librecode0_3.6-21_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fortune-mod/fortune-mod_1.99.1-7_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fortune-mod/fortunes-min_1.99.1-7_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fortune-mod/fortunes_1.99.1-7_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I think the error come from apt-get update but when I do it on my computer I got no problem.
I'm running ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem, the error is a connectivity issue within the container.

I have found other topic about this problem for people not using a personnal wifi network.

So I just run the command using 3G from my phone and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to adjust you update command as per the error message:

> Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: I had the --fix-missing to my dockerfil now I've got no error for the apt-get update but the install is still not working

Comment: Which is a different question.

Comment: no it's the same question, the same error from the tutorial